# What is the Japanese release date of Evangelion: 3.0+1.0?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion, rebuild-of-evangelion

Has an official Japanese release date for **[Evangelion: 3.0+1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelion:_3.0%2B1.0)** been announced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no official announcement, any date not published by Khara is only rumor. The most recent news related to this is that Hideaki Anno was working on Godzilla and in Decemeber, [Khara was recruiting more staff](http://www.khara.co.jp/recruiting/). The recruiting could be related to other projects, like the Animator Expo. In other news, Shuichi Iseki posted some pictures that looks like Khara is moving to a new location (maybe). There's no confirmation that all the recruitment and perhaps moving to a larger space has *anything* to do with the Evangelion movie. So some speculation:

1. It has to do with Eva, so maybe the movie isn't done yet
2. It has to do with something else that's not Eva, so maybe the movie isn't done and they're not going to finish it or

   - The movie is done but delayed for some other reason.